# How to create name for the textField dynamically [SWIFT]?

Tags: swift, swift3

How to create name for the textField dynamically for next parsing value, which will be the name of the textField? It will looks like **UID_score**.
***UID*** - this is user id, which is fetching from CoreData.

Comment: At the best of my knowledge, it's impossible to create a text field name dynamically in swift.

Comment: And what can i do? Maybe you know how to do something like this?

Comment: I'm creating dynamic tableView with users and every user must have textField for inputting score value, how can i initialize each textField for each user? And then send it into CoreData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure about what you want to achieve, but one way to generate a number of TextFields that match with the number of user Ids could be as follows. You can also set `tag` of the TextField to keep track of each user.

```
let userIds = [5, 8, 9, 10, 12]
let textFields = (0 ..< userIds.count).map { _ in UITextField() }
for i in 0..<userIds.count {
    textFields[i].frame = CGRect(x: 10 * i, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
    textFields[i].tag = userIds[i]
    view.addSubview(textFields[i])
}
```